# Need to reverse the listview after retriving data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a created an android app.In my app when people click on the button it goes to requestlist activity and displays all the name and description. Every data is stored in the firebase. firebase store data serially one by one below one another.Thats why when I fetch data from firebase the list shows everything serially.. But i want to show last data at top. How I can do that.

Here is my  activity its names requestList

```
RequestList.java

String description;
ArrayList<String> RequestList;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_list);


    RequestList = new ArrayList<>();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_request);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.list, RequestList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);





    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Request");



    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            RequestName Request = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestName.class);
            String requestInfo = "Name : "+ Request.requestname + "   \nDescription : " +  Request.description;
            RequestList.add(requestInfo);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

here's the layout

```
activity_request_list



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_request"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="@color/red"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip" />
```

I have used a custom layout for display

```
list_item

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/White" />
```

Please help

Comment: I'm not sure how efficient this is, but perhaps you could reverse your list using `Collections.reverse(list);`

Comment: @ZUNJAE  I actually tried this once when I had the same problem as Nahid does. onChildAdded is called when every single node is retrieved from Firebase. That means: you retrieve "a" and put it in the list then you reversed it. Then you fetched "b", the list becomes "a,b" you reversed it -> "b,a". Then you get "c" and list becomes "b,a,c" and reverse it "c,a,b". After third data node you get, it becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to add the `requestInfo` as the first element of the `RequestList`. This might solve your problem rather than reversing all the list.

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        RequestName request = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestName.class);
        String requestInfo = "Name : "+ Request.requestname + "   \nDescription : " +  Request.description;
        RequestList.add(0, requestInfo);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Other methods are removed for simplicity. 
});
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection for reverse like :- Collection.reverse(RequestList);

```
RequestList = new ArrayList<>();

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_request);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.list, RequestList);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);





DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Request");



myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        RequestName Request = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestName.class);
        String requestInfo = "Name : "+ Request.requestname + "   \nDescription : " +  Request.description;
        RequestList.add(requestInfo);
       Collection.reverse(RequestList);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});mpElements);
```

Comment: I actually tried this once when I had the same problem as @Nahid does. onChildAdded is called when every single node is retrieved from Firebase. That means: you retrieve "a"  and put it in the list then you reversed it. Then you fetched "b", the list becomes "a,b" you reversed it -> "b,a". Then you get "c" and list becomes "b,a,c" and reverse it "c,a,b". After third data node you get, it becomes useless.

Comment: I have tried It's working you can put also outside of addChildEventListener.